# Serializing a String with Data.Cereal or Data.Binary

Tags: haskell

I am implementing a protocol that dictates that a string representing a password should be serialized to a fixed length, 10-byte field. I am using Data.Cereal to perform this task. Here's my most recent go at it:

```
padText :: Int -> Text -> Text
padText fieldLen = T.justifyLeft fieldLen '\NUL'

putPassword :: Putter Password
putPassword = put . TE.encodeUtf8 . padText 10
```

put on ByteStrings prepends an additional 8-byte chunk onto the front of what it is encoding making:

```
 runPut $ putPassword "Friend"
```

result in :

```
"\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\nFriend\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL"
```

I don't want the extra chunk. Why is put behaving this way?

Does anyone know how to serialize only the 10 original bytes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume by "the extra chunk" you mean the first bit of `"\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\n`.  That is a 64 bit length field (notice it's value is `10`) which is part of the Serialize definition for `ByteString`. Since you already have a bytestring after calling `TE.encodeUtf8`, I suggest you just use `putByteString` to avoid the length field (or `putLazyByteString` if you're importing a lazy text encoding module).

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas stated `put` on ByteStrings prepends the encoded length. Shown
below is the actual instance:

```
instance Serialize B.ByteString where
    put bs = do put (B.length bs :: Int)
                putByteString bs
   ...
```

`putByteString` alone does not. The solution is to use `putByteString`:

```
putPassword :: Putter Password
putPassword = putByteString . TE.encodeUtf8 . padText 10
```